# Validating input field in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let us consider we have a function for validating all fields in the form. If I am changing the input of one particular field, the only field that has been changed should be validated but not other fields.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please share your code.

Comment: You can separate validate methods for each field, then you attach those methods to each field by use onchange or onblur method

Comment: Yes. we can by using seperate functions for each field. but i need this by using a single function. can we send any identity from the field, so we can just call a particular validation?

Comment: If your fields are fixed, then we can send the name of the field using onchange or onblur function. In the validate method, we will base on the particular name to validate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can use `.bind()` function to trigger on the change of the input box.

```
$("element").bind('change', function({}));
```

Comment: Mate, when posting code please format it. For in-line code, enclose the code within the ` symbol. For multi-line code either indent the line by 4 spaces (or) use `{}` button present in the button bar.

Comment: Hey @Harry, thanks for the guidance.. will keep this in mind.